# Is Reentrant Lock a Object level lock or Class level lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, reentrantlock

I see in many tutorials for Reentrant lock, they create a new Reentrant lock and resource is injected, lock and unlock of reentrant lock is called in try/finally block. I don't understand the connection between this lock and resource which is used in the thread. Below is an example of tutorial on Reentrant lock

Resource code

```
public class Resource {

    public void doSomething(){
        //do some operation, DB read, write etc
    }
    
    public void doLogging(){
        //logging, no need for thread safety
    }
}
```

Resource being used in thread declaration code

```
public class ConcurrencyLockExample implements Runnable{

    private Resource resource;
    private Lock lock;
    
    public ConcurrencyLockExample(Resource r){
        this.resource = r;
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(lock.tryLock(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)){
            resource.doSomething();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            //release lock
            lock.unlock();
        }
        resource.doLogging();
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me how this prevents multiple threads from accessing the given resource at same time resulting in race condition???
Is this reentrant lock creating a Object level lock or Class level lock in the resource???

Comment: `Resource` is just an object with a `doSomething()` method.  `ReentrantLock` is just a lock object with additional capabilities; see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).

Comment: The way it prevents multiple threads from accessing the resource is this: `lock.tryLock()` returns `false`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "object level lock" or "class level lock".  It's not `static` if that's what you mean.  Each `ConcurrencyLockExample` object contains its own `ReentrantLock` object.  Presumably, each ConcurrencyLockExample object can only handle one thread at a time, but you can have multiple such objects, each handling its own series of `run()` calls.

Comment: It is neither. It is a lock, period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one sense, a `ReentrantLock` is neither a class-level nor an object-level lock. In a more practical sense, it's the same as either of them.

Really, you should forget about "class level" and "object level" locking. Those are not useful distinctions.

You can use *any* object as the `lock` in a `synchronized(lock){...}` block. "Object level" locking simply means that, within some method of a `class C`, the object that you choose is an instance of the class; and "class level" means that you choose to use `C.class` as the lock object.

But, you can use other objects too,* and `synchronized(lock)` behaves in the same way no matter what object you choose for the `lock`.

---

* This is a pattern that often is used by experienced software developers:

```java
public class C {
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public MyType myMethod(...) {
        ...
        synchronized(lock) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The reason for using a `private` object is that the author of some client code that uses class `C` potentially could use an instance of `C` as a lock. That wouldn't be a smart idea, but nothing prevents them from doing it. If two different authors chose to use the same object as a lock, there could be unforseen interactions (e.g., in the worst case, a deadlock.) But the author of class `C` averts that problem by using a `lock` object that is inaccessible to other classes.